# How to connect to PostgreSQL using docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, service, docker-compose

Want to use `docker-compose` to run api application and postgresql database together.

`docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  database_data:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    build: ./api
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app/
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
```

Api `main.go` file:

```
func main() {
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=db port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres")
  // ...
}
```

When run the services, got message from log:

```
api_1     | [GIN] 2018/06/22 - 07:31:10 | 404 |      1.4404ms |      172.20.0.1 | GET      /posts
api_1     |
api_1     | (sql: database is closed)
api_1     | [2018-06-22 07:31:10]
api_1     |
api_1     | (sql: database is closed)
api_1     | [2018-06-22 07:31:10]
api_1     | [GIN] 2018/06/22 - 07:32:14 | 403 |        15.6µs |      172.20.0.1 | GET      /posts
db_1      | 2018-06-22 07:34:27.296 UTC [81] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
db_1      | 2018-06-22 07:34:36.897 UTC [90] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Does this way not good? `host=db` in the connection string? Since `db` is the docker compose service name.

---

## Add

It can work:

https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#-or-via-psql

Comment: Looks like you need to expose the port for postgres

Comment: @DominicBarnes It doesn't matter: `db_1      | 2018-06-22 08:43:58.702 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432`.

Comment: have you trying adding `network_mode: host`?

Comment: @mulg0r No, how to add it?

Comment: I see 2 things here: (1) fix the `FATAL` errors you get from your `db`, (2) make sure that `api` will try to connect after `db` is ready.

Comment: @vv even if postgres is _listening_ on that port, that does not mean that docker is sending traffic for that port through. You need to add `ports: - 5432:5432` to your docker-compose config, as all ports are closed by default.

Comment: @DominicBarnes Even I set to `ports: - 5432:5432`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 30):

In the [link](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#-or-via-psql) you provided there are configuration settings that you did not added

```
restart: always
environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

You should try this

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    build: ./api
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app/
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - PGHOST: 'db'
      - PGDATABASE: 'postgres'
      - PGUSER: 'postgres'
      - PGPASSWORD: 'postgres'


volumes:
  database_data:
    driver: local
```

and

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=db port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres password=postgres")
```